# Macro variable after class keyword

Tags: c++, macros

I found this in Ogre Framework

```
class _OgreSampleClassExport Sample_Character : public SdkSample {
...
...
```

and it's define like this

```
#define _OgreSampleClassExport
```

Why we want to have this macro variable?

Answer (score 5):

Presumably so a special qualifier, such as [`__declspec(dllexport)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), could be added to such classes by modifying (or conditionally defining) the define:

```
#define _OgreSampleClassExport __declspec(dllexport)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's to allow for future exports. Ogre may just strictly be a statically linked library at the moment, but if the authors ever decide to support dynamically-linked libraries (aka shared libraries on some platforms), they will need to write code like:

```
class
#ifdef EXPORTING
    __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
Sample_Character [...]
```

... and that's just for MSVC. Normally they'd have to go through the effort to do this to Sample_Character and all other classes they provide through their library. Making a single macro to be defined later is much easier as they'll only need to do this in one place.