# Class declarations

Tags: c++, class

So I'm looking at the Ogre Character sample, and there's a class which is declared as

```
class _OgreSampleClassExport Sample_Character : public SdkSample
```

The classes identifier is Sample_Character and it is derived from the SdkSample class. What is the _OgreSampleClassExport though?

Comment: Probably a synonym (that's also a reserved identifier) for `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: Looks like the _Ogre Character sample_ is not standard conformant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows platforms `_OgreSampleClassExport` is a macro used to specify the DLL linkage of a class' members. If the macro expands to `__declspec(dllimport)` the members exist in an external DLL and must be imported. If it expands to `__declspec(dllexport)` the members exist in the DLL being built and will be exported. If the macro is blank the members will be linked statically and do not exit in a DLL.

On other platforms it works in much the same way. On Linux when compiling with GCC the macro expands to [`__attribute__ ((visibility("???")))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) where "???" specifies the linkage in a similar fashion as that used in to `__declspec()`.

Answer (score 1):

This post seems relevant - 
[Macro variable after class keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146301/macro-variable-after-class-keyword)

Essentially, it allows for the class to be exported to support a dynamically-linked library.